# Checking for array or Json values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check, if certain words exist, but as far as I have tried, it seems not to be working.

```
 Chars = {
    ae: 'hello',
    oe: 'world',
};

if(ae in Chars){
    document.write('yes');
}else{
    document.write('no');
}
```

I am just trying to know, if `ae` exists

Comment: Note that your code doesn't use JSON - what you have is an object created from an object literal. (JSON is a string format used for data interchange.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

[object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if(Chars.hasOwnProperty('ae'))
{
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
if(Chars.ae){...}
else {...}
```

Comment: But, I have over 100 `ae` like values to check, is there anyway this could be done with loops, instead of 100 `if/elseif` or `switch()` ? thanks btw

Comment: @Kuntilak An object can't have multiple properties of the same name. The last one will overwrite all others.

Comment: I tried your code now, it does not work, can you double check?

Comment: @Kuntilak I don't know how you are using it, [but it works here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xag3W/)

Comment: Note that this works only if you know in advance that the value associated with `ae` can't be an empty string (or other falsy value).

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn I got it now

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single value that you know at coding time, you can do

```
if (Chars.ae !== undefined) {
    document.write('yes');
}
else {
    document.write('no');
}
```

If you want to be able to figure these out dynamically at runtime, like say you have a variable representing the property to check, then you can use the bracket notation.

```
Chars = {
    ae: 'hello',
    oe: 'world',
    .. bunch of other properties
};

function doesCharEntryExist(entry) {
    return Chars[entry] !== undefined;
}

console.log(doesCharEntryExist('ae'));
console.log(doesCharEntryExist('oe'));
console.log(doesCharEntryExist('blah'));
```

outputs

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: Note that `if (Chars.ae) {` works only if you know in advance that the associated value can't be an empty string (or other falsy value).

Comment: I meant to check for undefined, which I did in the second part.  Updated the first one.  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

To use the `in` operator you need to put `ae` in quotes:

```
if ("ae" in Chars){
```

Or you can use a variable as follows:

```
var valueToTest = "ae";
if (valueToTest in Chars) {
```

You said in a comment under another answer that you have over one hundred values to check. You don't say how you are managing those hundred, but assuming they're in an array you can use a loop:

```
var keyNamesToTest = ["ae", "xy", "zz", "oe"];
for (var i = 0; i < keyNamesToTest.length; i++) {
    if (keyNamesToTest[i] in Chars){
        document.write('yes');
        // key name exists - to get the value use Chars[keyNamesToTest[i]]
    }else{
        document.write('no');
    }
}
```

For the `Chars` object you showed with the test array I introduced you'd get a yes, two nos, and another yes.